# how to map an anonymous object to a class by AutoMapper?

Tags: c#, mapping, automapper, anonymous-types

I have an entity:

```
public class Tag {
    public int Id { get; set; }
    public string Word { get; set; }
    // other properties...
    // and a collection of blogposts:
    public ICollection<Post> Posts { get; set; }
}
```

and a model:

```
public class TagModel {
    public int Id { get; set; }
    public string Word { get; set; }
    // other properties...
    // and a collection of blogposts:
    public int PostsCount { get; set; }
}
```

and I query the entity like this (by **EF** or **NH**):

```
var tagsAnon = _context.Tags
    .Select(t => new { Tag = t, PostsCount = t. Posts.Count() })
    .ToList();
```

Now, how can I map the `tagsAnon` (as an *anonymous object*) to a collection of `TagModel` (e.g. `ICollection<TagModel>` or `IEnumerable<TagModel>`)? Is it possible?

Comment: Why not map `Tag` directly to `TagModel`? Why the intermediate object?

Comment: @AndrewWhitaker because Entity Framework only understands anonymous types in the `Select`, and can optimize the SQL query from it.

Answer (score 63):

**Update 2019-07-31**: [`CreateMissingTypeMaps` is now deprecated in AutoMapper v8, and will be removed in v9](https://github.com/AutoMapper/AutoMapper/issues/3063).

> *Support for automatically created maps will be removed in version 9.0.*
>   *You will need to explicitly configure maps, manually or using*
>   *reflection. Also consider [attribute mapping](http://docs.automapper.org/en/latest/Attribute-mapping.html).*

---

**Update 2016-05-11**: [DynamicMap is now obsolete](https://github.com/AutoMapper/AutoMapper/wiki/Migrating-from-static-API#unsupported-operations).

Now you need to create a mapper from a configuration that sets `CreateMissingTypeMaps` to `true`:

```
var tagsAnon = Tags
    .Select(t => new { t.Id, t.Word, PostsCount = t.Posts.Count })
    .ToList();

var config = new MapperConfiguration(cfg => cfg.CreateMissingTypeMaps = true);
var mapper = config.CreateMapper();

var tagsModel = tagsAnon.Select(mapper.Map<TagModel>)
    .ToList();
```

---

Yes, it is possible. You would have to use the `DynamicMap<T>` method of the Automapper's `Mapper` class for each anonymous object you have. Something like this:

```
var tagsAnon = Tags
    .Select(t => new { t.Id, t.Word, PostsCount = t.Posts.Count() })
    .ToList();

var tagsModel = tagsAnon.Select(Mapper.DynamicMap<TagModel>)
    .ToList();
```

Comment: This is deprecated as of AutoMapper 4.1, what to do now?

Comment: @MobileMon I've updated the answer with the new way of doing it. Thanks for pointing it out.

Comment: I can confirm using "CreateMissingTypeMaps = true" works. This answer should be marked as valid. Thanks!

Comment: CreateMissingTypeMaps = true works like charm. But is there a good way to create a generic function for this? Something like "private static T MapDynamic<T>(dynamic obj)".. I can't get it right. Any comments?

Comment: @vohrahul I'm sure I understand your question. Maybe you want to post a new question with more details and more code (even if pseudo-code that doesn't compile) to show what you're trying to do?

Comment: @CaioProiete Hey, I am sorry I forgot to update. But I actually got it to working and posted the same as an answer here on this question itself.

Comment: The CreateMissingTypeMaps = true is also deprecated on the 8.1.1.0 version. I guess the easiest way now is to map field by field.

Comment: So with version 9 it's no longer possible to map anon types to a class? Or is there another way?

Comment: @C. Augusto Proiete.  CreateMissingTypeMaps is also obsolete in ver > 9.  Any suggestions?

Comment: Support for automatically created maps will be removed in version 9.0. You will need to explicitly configure maps, manually or using reflection. Also consider [attribute mapping](http://docs.automapper.org/en/latest/Attribute-mapping.html)

Answer (score 4):

I am not entirely sure if this is possible. Suggestions:

Why can't you just do this:

```
var tagsAnon = _context.Tags
    .Select(t => new TagModel { Tag = t, PostsCount = t. Posts.Count() })
    .ToList();
```

This SHOULD work, however it fails (I have read that DynamicMap is iffy on collections.

```
var destination = Mapper.DynamicMap<IEnumerable<TagModel>>(tagsAnon);
```

This proves that DynamicMap does work with anon types, just not seemingly with enumerables:

```
var destination = Mapper.DynamicMap<TagModel>(tagsAnon);
```

Answer (score 0):

You can create a custom function to achieve this with latest Automapper. It uses the `CreateMissingTypeMaps` property as mentioned in other answers above.

```
public static List<T> MapDynamicList<T>(IEnumerable<object> obj)
    {
        var config = new MapperConfiguration(c => c.CreateMissingTypeMaps = true);
        var mapper = config.CreateMapper();

        var newModel = obj.Select(mapper.Map<T>).ToList();

        return newModel;
    }
```

Then you just call the function with this single line of code:

```
var viewModel = Models.Helper.MapDynamicList<MatchSubCategory>(model);
```

where `model` is the `IEnumerable<object>` or `List<object>`.

Comment: Creating a new mapper every time would have a cost to it. It would often be better to assign the mapper-instance to a private static variable.