# how to convert anonymous type to known type

Tags: c#, class, mapping, anonymous-class

I have an anonymous type variable. This variable is get from another function, we couldn't change it.

```
// var a {property1 = "abc"; property2 = "def"}
```

I have a class:

```
class Myclass{
   string property1;
   string property2;
}
```

How to convert variable `a` to `Myclass` type. I tried

```
Myclass b = (Myclass)a;
```

but it doesn't work.

If I initialize:

```
Myclass b = new Myclass{
  property1 = a.property1,
  property2 = a.property2,
}
```

it is working, but it take a lot of code because `MyClass` has many properties

Can anyone help me? Thanks for any answer.

Comment: You can't cast it, because these types are not related. You can use mapping library, e.g. automapper, to do work for you if you really don't want to write initialization code.

Comment: [using AutoMapper](http://stackoverflow.com/a/10465897/491243)

Answer (score 10, accepted):

You can't use casting here, because neither you anonymous type inherited from `MyClass` nor you have [explicit type conversion operator](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/xhbhezf4.aspx) defined for these types.

You can use [AutoMapper](http://automapper.org/) (available from NuGet) to dynamically map between anonymous type and your class

```
var a = new {property1 = "abc", property2 = "def"};
Myclass b = Mapper.DynamicMap<Myclass>(a);
```

It maps properties of anonymous object to properties of destination type by name:

[image]

Comment: @JohnNguyen follow the link, or you can simply find AutoMapper in NuGet

Comment: Thanks for letting me know about conversion operators.