# How to use AutoMapper to map from a strongly typed List to an array list of type: object

Tags: c#, automapper

I need to map a DTO object to an object that my webservice will accept.

DTO object:

```
public class TerminationCause
{
    // other properties...

    public List<TerminationCauseServicePurchase> TerminationCauseServicePurchase { get; set; }

    public TerminationCause()
    {
        TerminationCauseServicePurchase = new List<TerminationCauseServicePurchase>();
    }
}
```

Web service object:

```
public partial class TerminationCause
{
    public object[] TerminationCauseServicePurchase { get; set; }

    // other properties...
}
```

All the "other properties" have the same names and the TerminationCauseServicePurchase classes are identical. The problem is that the field TerminationCauseServicePurchase does not get mapped.

Here are the mappings:

```
Mapper.CreateMap<DTO.TerminationCause, ExternalUdbudsportal.TerminationCause>();
Mapper.CreateMap<DTO.TerminationCauseServicePurchase, ExternalUdbudsportal.TerminationCauseServicePurchase>();
```

TerminationCause object gets mapped properly, but it's inner list "TerminationCauseServicePurchase"  remains the same type (DTO.TerminationCauseServicePurchase instead of ExternalUdbudsportal.TerminationCauseServicePurchase), which the web service does not accept.

The map method:

```
upEkst.TerminationCause tmpTC = Mapper.Map<DTO.TerminationCause, upEkst.TerminationCause>(tc);
```

Comment: Why are you using an `object[]` instead of an interface array? I believe it is going to be difficult to get AutoMapper to work with an object[], but maybe not.

Comment: This is what the WSDL of the web service has provided me with. Is it a good idea to change it? Is there a workaround?

Comment: @TyCobb My thoughts exactly.

Comment: @Kenci Btw I didn't -1 u... but i believe others r because you have a shed load of code that is irrelevent, thus requiring others to read it.

Comment: @Kenci It seems similar to mapping anonymous objects... tricky... http://stackoverflow.com/questions/9639451/how-to-map-an-anonymous-object-to-a-class-by-automapper

Comment: @PaulZahra i reduced the amount of code. Will look into your answer.

Comment: You can take help from my answer here in this post. https://stackoverflow.com/a/50439420/2803872

Answer (score 0):

My solution:

Since AutoMapper doesn't map the inner `object[]` array automatically, i took out the `List<TerminationCauseServicePurchase>` from the DTO `TerminationCause` object and used AutoMapper to map it explicitly.

```
upEkst.TerminationCause tmpTC = Mapper.Map<DTO.TerminationCause, upEkst.TerminationCause>(tc);
var tmpTCSPList = Mapper.Map<List<DTO.TerminationCauseServicePurchase>,
upEkst.TerminationCauseServicePurchase[]>(tc.TerminationCauseServicePurchase);
tmpTC.TerminationCauseServicePurchase = tmpTCSPList;
```

Answer (score 0):

You can create a custom function to achieve this with latest Automapper. It uses the CreateMissingTypeMaps property.

```
public static T[] MapDynamicList<T>(IEnumerable<YOUR_CUSTOM_CLASS> obj)
    {
        var config = new MapperConfiguration(c => c.CreateMissingTypeMaps = true);
        var mapper = config.CreateMapper();

        var newModel = obj.Select(mapper.Map<T>).ToArray();

        return newModel;
    }
```

Then you just call the function with this single line of code:

```
var viewModel = Models.Helper.MapDynamicList<object>(model);
```

where `model` is the IEnumerable or List.